# Partner Community - Partner Account Id

Tags: partner-communities

I have set up a Partner Community.
One of the tiles I want to open the partner's own Account within my Salesforce.
I set up Link Type = Community Page

Page = Account Details

URL = /account/{Account Id}

How do I get the logged in user account id to merge it into the URL?

Comment: Where do you want to use it, in a formula field? There is AccountId field on user which you could use.

Comment: @Raul I need to merge the partner user account id to the URL

Comment: @Dedo In Community Builder, when we create a page where you can pass the partner user Account Id.

Comment: @Raul I am using a Tile design and in the Tile I can specify the id of the account page to open. I need to somehow get the logged user account id as a merge field